# Magic Resistance and Destructive Wrath

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, cleric, saving-throw

Currently hit a debate within our campaign in regards to a [bearded devil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bearded-devil) gaining advantage on a Saving Throw from Magic Resistance when our Tempest Cleric can use their Channel Divinity for Destructive Wrath.

I have already checked these two posts: [How do I know if an ability is magical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113364/how-do-i-know-if-an-ability-is-magical) and [When does a Tempest cleric have to choose to use Destructive Wrath?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82952/when-does-a-tempest-cleric-have-to-choose-to-use-destructive-wrath).

If the Cleric uses his Wrath of the Storm ability to deal Thunder/Lightning damage the target has to make a Dex Save. As per the Sage Advice this is not magical and therefore isn't made at advantage by a creature with Magic Resistance.

If the Destructive Wrath is used as a Channel Divinity it gains the wording "fuel magical effects" and would therefore become magical for the purpose of Magic Resistance, however the most upvoted post on Destructive Wrath puts the damage being rolled after the saving throw and thus applied after the saving throw is made.

My question is what would be the best way to apply the rules in this example?

Would you apply the Destructive Wrath after the saving throw has been made thus detrimenting the creature, or would you apply the Destructive Wrath before the saving throw thus (potentially) detrimenting the player?

Answer (score 5):

### Magic Resistance should not apply

Normally, you roll damage only after the saving throw is made (it's same logic of an attack roll), and you can use your Destructive Wrath "when you roll lightning or thunder damage".

Furthermore, whilst it's true that Destructive Wrath is magical as per all Channel Divinity effects, this feature is not the one calling for the save. The feature calling for the save is Wrath of the Storms, which has nothing in its text that would tag it as magical for this purpose.